# loop Nsmutable arrray of uiimages from end to beginning

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, loops, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMUtable  array of images where a different image is displayed with a previous and a next button, but when I get to the end of the array the simulator crashes. I want to loop the end of the array to the beginning so that when I get to the end of the array of images when I hit the next button again it loops back to the first image, also when Im at the first image if I hit the previous button it loops to the last image with no crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a circular array, which is easy to implement using a standard `NSMutableArray`.  For instance, say you store your images in an array called `imageArray` and use a simple variable to keep track of the index of your current image, like:

```
int currentImageIndex = 0;
```

...then you might implement `nextImage` and `previousImage` like:

```
- (UIImage*) nextImage {
    currentImageIndex = (currentImageIndex + 1) % [imageArray count];
    return [imageArray objectAtIndex:currentImageIndex];
}

- (UIImage*) previousImage {
    currentImageIndex--;
    if (currentImageIndex < 0) {
        currentImageIndex = [imageArray count] - 1;
    }

    return [imageArray objectAtIndex:currentImageIndex];
}
```

Then just use `nextImage` and `previousImage` whenever you want to step through the array, and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough to do. all you need to do is create a check to see if you're on the last element, and if so, set your tracker (like count or i etc) to 0 again,

Heres the psudo code
    //set index

```
if ( array [ index ] == len(array) - 1) //at end
{
  index = 0
}

if(array [index] == -1)//at beginning
{
  index = len(array) -1
}
// do something with array[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to propose this solution:

A property for the selected UIImage, a NSInteger property to hold the current index.

```
-(IBAction) nextButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    self.currentIndex = self.currentIndex++ % [self.images count];
    self.selectedImage= [self.images objectAtIndex:self.currentIndex];
    [self reloadImageView];
}

-(IBAction) previousButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    self.currentIndex--;
    if (self.currentIndex < 0)
        self.currentIndex += [self.images count];
    self.selectedImage= [self.images objectAtIndex:self.currentIndex];
    [self reloadImageView];
}

-(void)reloadImageView
{
    //do, what is necessary to display new image. Animation?

}
```